# Are there quality standards for videos/gifs posted here?

Tags: discussion

In the answer

[Can we stop scriptures sourced from a self-declared non-Hindu faith from being cited as Hindu scripture?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/can-we-stop-scriptures-sourced-from-a-self-declared-non-hindu-faith-from-being-c)

I find the gif here crude and offensive.

Comment: Is there voting to close for silliness?

Comment: Relax.. it's just a gif. It is  only saying nope. Saying "nope" is offensive?

Comment: I guess the answer is there are no standards.  Whatever the clique in control deems fit goes.

Comment: Wow. I will start using Gif in my answers then. You can also use. Never knew it was allowed. ;)

Comment: @Rohit. The question is about offensiveness and the gif is not offensive. That doesn't mean we encourage posting gifs.

Comment: @Pandya Okay I will post/use non offensive gifs & emojis. Actually I'm in support of using gifs/emojis etc. Just knew today it is allowed.

Comment: @Rohit. There is no rule that it is allowed or not allowed. I used it for some comic sense which OP didn't find it funny. Meta debates are always serious. If someone has stopped at gif instead of the explanation I gave, then it is not a good way to vote.

Comment: I don't understand why it was added.. for me it makes the answer look irritating..@SK

Comment: It is interesting that we can use gifs! My first ever answer here included a friendly salutation and I signed off with "नमस्ते ". I was told neither of those are allowed. Even though I think removing these makes it easier to misperceive people as hostile when they are not (because there is no body language or tone in text) I have continued to follow the rule I was told. Having said that, I do believe the use of such gifs makes the site seem as untrustworthy as Yahoo Answers. On the other hand, most people who come across the site aren't interested in Meta.

Answer (score 7):

> I find the gif here crude and offensive.

I don't find any offense with the gif. That gif is just saying No. You can find similar [answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169210/260388) also!

If that answer was gif/image-only without any explanation, it can be considered of low quality but [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1245/277) provides enough explanation and anyway, not violating the Be-Nice policy. So nothing is offensive in this case.

Comment: Are emojis also allowed then? They should be if Gifs are.

Comment: It feels like "talk to the hand" that African Americans use.  But then I have low expectations about quality at this site  anyway.

Comment: "If that answer was gif/image-only without any explanation, it can be considered of low quality" @pandya what is the gif adding to the answer, except swagger?

Comment: @SK Yes, it is adding some fun to others. Not all find it offensive. We should have some fun.

Comment: Why should we use gif in first place at all  . This is not a comic site

Comment: @AnuragSingh This is not a comic site. Yup. We are here to fight. Let's fight. Come on. (: